# How do I show the Subscriber Count in a MailChimp Form?

Tags: wordpress, mailchimp

I am using a MailChimp Form on my WordPress site to capture interested people into a MailChimp newsletter list. At the start I faked the number of people who have registered, but now that I have a few, I would like to get the number of subscribers through a form variable.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have missed it, but the Variables list on the form editor does contain the option you're looking for:

```
{subscriber_count}
```